# Update state object's property with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I have init state like this:

```
  let initState = {
    checkBoxValues:{
        react: false,
        angular: false,
        vue: true,
        python: false,
        java: true
    }
  };
```

And my reducer :

```
export default (state = initState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){

    case "SET_CHECKBOX":
        let {name,checked}= action;

        return  {...state, checkBoxValues: ?????? }

    default:
        return state

    }
}
```

how can I update my state?
For example name is "react" and checked is true.

```
  let {name,checked}= action;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update it without mutation like this

```
return  {...state, checkBoxValues: {...state.checkBoxValues,[name]: checked } }
```